# Merge monitors for a specific application

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

So I have a triple-monitor setup and I know I can "merge them" (through the Nvidia control panel) as if they were one big 5760x1080 monitor instead of 3 separate 1920x1080 one. What bugs me about this approach is that when I come back to 3 monitors, my icons are all over the place and my windows are all stacked which is slightly annoying.

What I'd like to know, is can I do this merging, but for only specific applications (e.g. video games) ? That way I could play a game in 5760x1080 and then alt-tab to my "regular" 3 * (1920x1080) desktop with all my other applications where I left them?

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Ultramon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/). It will allow you to better control the windows desktop across all the screens without using the Nvidia option.

Ben